# How do I filter array that sometimes has a value of null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to filter an array and only get the values where HasAccess is set to false. The only problem is that HasAccess does not always exist. Sometimes Settings is null. How can I manage this?

```
    0:{
ClientCodeRegional: (2) ["29000-A", "122214"]
CreatedUpdatedBy: null
Email: "testuserthree@for.deletion"
Id: "11ad1dfb-3cd6-4db6-87a9-8063bb12504d"
Settings: {
          CsmPassword: ""
          CsmUser: ""
          HasAccess: false
          IsAdmin: true
          IsInternal: false
          IsLocked: true
          MarketAreaCode: ""
          Role: "Administrator"
          Updated: null
          UpdatedBy: null
          UserId: "11ad1dfb-3cd6-4db6-87a9-8063bb12504d"
          }
}
```

I tried a lot of different things but this is what I got at the moment.

```
const users = result.data.filter((number) => {

          //number.Settings != null
           if (typeof number.Settings == "null") {
            return true;
          } else {
            return number;
          }
          })
```

Comment: You are returning true if Setting == "null", that means to keep that element not filter out if it is "null", Also "null" is not same as null.

Comment: it's worth noting that there is [a famous and long-standing bug in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#null) whereby `typeof null` results in `"object"`. No value `x` actually has `typeof x == "null"`

Comment: @chriss - OP is using `typeof`.

Comment: Sry missread but thank you both for point out, other problem of always returning value, meaning not filtering, is still valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to get all entries for which `Settings.HasAccess` is defined and is `false`**, use a logical and (`&&`) to check if the `settings` object exists first and then compare the `HasAccess` property with `false` using `===`.

Here `true` will be returned only if `Settings` exists and has an `HasAccess` property set to false.

```js
const result = {
  data: [
    { Settings: { HasAccess: true  }, a: 1 },
    { Settings: { HasAccess: false }, a: 2 },
    { Settings: {                  }, a: 3 },
    {                                 a: 4 }
  ]
};

const users = result.data.filter(item => {
  return item.Settings && item.Settings.HasAccess === false;
})

console.log(users);
```

**If you want to get all results for which `HasAccess` is not defined or falsy**, use or instead (`||`) with the not operator (`!`).

Here true will be returned if:

- `Settings` does not exist
- `HasAccess` property is not defined
- `HasAccess` exists but its value is falsy (null, undefined, false)

```js
const result = {
  data: [
    { Settings: { HasAccess: true  }, a: 1 },
    { Settings: { HasAccess: false }, a: 2 },
    { Settings: {                  }, a: 3 },
    {                                 a: 4 }
  ]
};

const users = result.data.filter(item => {
  return !item.Settings || !item.Settings.HasAccess;
})

console.log(users);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to filter an array and only get the values where HasAccess is
>   set to false,Sometimes Settings is null

Just check for `Settings && (HasAccess === false)`

```js
let arr = [{ClientCodeRegional:["29000-A","122214"],CreatedUpdatedBy:null,Email:"testuserthree@for.deletion",Id:"11ad1dfb-3cd6-4db6-87a9-8063bb12504d",Settings:{CsmPassword:"",CsmUser:"",HasAccess:false,IsAdmin:true,IsInternal:false,IsLocked:true,MarketAreaCode:"",Role:"Administrator",Updated:null,UpdatedBy:null,UserId:"11ad1dfb-3cd6-4db6-87a9-8063bb12504d",}},{ClientCodeRegional:["29000-A","122214"],CreatedUpdatedBy:null,Email:"testuserthree@for.deletion",Id:"11ad1dfb-3cd6-4db6-87a9-8063bb12504d",Settings:{CsmPassword:"",CsmUser:"",HasAccess:null,IsAdmin:true,IsInternal:false,IsLocked:true,MarketAreaCode:"",Role:"Administrator",Updated:null,UpdatedBy:null,UserId:"11ad1dfb-3cd6-4db6-87a9-8063bb12504d"}},{ClientCodeRegional:["29000-A","122214"],CreatedUpdatedBy:null,Email:"testuserthree@for.deletion",Id:"11ad1dfb-3cd6-4db6-87a9-8063bb12504d",Settings:{CsmPassword:"",CsmUser:"",//HasAccess:null,
IsAdmin:true,IsInternal:false,IsLocked:true,MarketAreaCode:"",Role:"Administrator",Updated:null,UpdatedBy:null,UserId:"11ad1dfb-3cd6-4db6-87a9-8063bb12504d"}}]

let op = arr.filter(({Settings})=> Settings && (Settings.HasAccess === false))
console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
if (number && number.Settings) {
  return number;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

Comment: `number.Settings !== 'null'` checks if it's the **string** `'null'`, not if it's the value `null`.

Comment: Separately, if you do a truthy test on `number.Settings` followed by `&&`, you **know** it's neither `null` nor `undefined`, as they're both falsy.